# How do I code this "Public Property Flow(NumCommodities - 1) As Double" in a VB.NET under a Class?

Tags: vb.net, properties

I am try to code this "Public Property Flow(NumCommodities - 1) As Double" under a class, but apparently it need additional coding.

So I need this property because I need to keep track of values based on this code:

```
For t As Integer = 0 To MyProblem.Arcs.Count-1
    For k = 0 To MyProblem.NumCommodities-1
        Dim i As Integer = MyProblem.Arcs(t).Tail
        Dim j As Integer = MyProblem.Arcs(t).Head
        Dim akey As String = "x(" & i & "," & j & "," & k & ")“
        Dim aid As Integer = solver.GetIndexFromKey(akey)
        MyProblem.Arcs(t).Flow(k) = solver.GetValue(aid).ToDouble
    Next
Next
```

OBS: I have already declared this under my MyProblem Class

```
Public Class MyProblem
    Public NumCommodities
```

Comment: What do you expect this property to do? Is the property supposed to return an array of Double? Or is it supposed to return a single item selected from an array or List?

Comment: it is supposed to return a single item selected from a list

Comment: Then see the latest update to Brandon B's answer.

Comment: VB.NET has very good support for indexed properties.  They don't look like that.  It is simply Public Property Flow(ByVal Index As Integer) As Double

Comment: But if simply put " Public Property Flow(NumCommodities-1) As Double", Visual Studios says: "Comma or ')' expected."

Comment: @JorgeHuang: Exactly. That's why you need to use the syntax in Hans Passant's comment, or in the second part of Brandon B's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare and array with a variable size. Instead you must declare and then initialize it.

```
Public Property Flow As Double() = New Double(NumCommodities - 1) {}
```

Note that this will fail if `NumCommodities - 1` is negative or if `NumCommodities` has not yet been instantiated.

Since your question does not provide a lot of insight to the issue, you may also be trying to declare a property that accesses an item of an array. Here is how you would implement such a thing:

```
Private _Flow As Double() = New Double() {}
Public Property Flow(ByVal NumCommodities As Int32) As Double
    Get
        Return _Flow(NumCommodities - 1)
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        _Flow(NumCommodities - 1) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: If you have correctly guessed the OP's intention, you need the property to return an array of Double, not a Double. `Public Property Flow() As Double() = New Double(NumCommodities - 1) {}`

Comment: Oops, You are correct. I put the set of `()` in the wrong place... it won't compile as is. However to use `()` in both the property and the type, wouldn't that be an array of arrays?

Comment: No, the () after the property name is where the arguments for property access would go. For example `Public Property Flow(numCommodities As Integer) As Double` could be used to access a single item (using numCommodities as the index) from an existing Double array. I think you may well have guessed the question correctly, and I agree that your updated code answers that question.

Comment: @Blackwood - Well, there's my brainfart for the day... I feel pretty useless right now, thanks (-_-)  I'll update the answer accordingly...